# Stacktrace loop

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

From time to time I see strange stack traces on our Java process in production. The stacktrace is very long and repeats just a few lines in a kind of a loop.

It prints:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
        at org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils.buildMessage(NestedExceptionUtils.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException.getMessage(NestedRuntimeException.java:77)
        at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
        at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
        at org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils.buildMessage(NestedExceptionUtils.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException.getMessage(NestedRuntimeException.java:77)
        at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
        at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
....
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
        at org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils.buildMessage(NestedExceptionUtils.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException.getMessage(NestedRuntimeException.java:77)
        at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
        at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
        at org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils.buildMessage(NestedExceptionUtils.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException.getMessage(NestedRuntimeException.java:77)
```

Currently we are using spring-core 5.1.5.RELEASE.
I'm not sure if I've seen this message with previous versions.

I will now update my spring core version to see if the error remains.

Has anybody seen this behaviour before or has some hints for me about what I should do?

Comment: Do you have any news? I have a similar error

Comment: Nope, unfortunately no.